# Does ending a python 2.7 print statement with a comma not work in tmux?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, tmux

Pretty much just what's in the question.  I have a slow process running in tmux and wanted to document progress through the for loop by printing the loop variable.

```
print 'Progress...', 
for i in range(15):
    ...
    print i, 
print
```

This works in my terminal. In tmux, however, it doesn't print anything until it hits a new-line command with the last print. Does printing on the same line repeatedly not work in tmux? How could I remedy this? It's not a  big deal, I'm just curious what I can do as I don't know much about bash scripting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost surely due to output buffering.  You can check that's the cause by calling flush:

```
import sys
print 'Progress...', 
for i in range(15):
    ...
    print i, 
    sys.stdout.flush()
print
```

If this fixes your problem, you might consider to run [python unbuffered](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: What's the difference between doing it in tmux vs. the terminal that tmux requires flushing the buffer? Do you know the reason behind why this is necessary?